# how to insert all text with Excel.Application

Tags: powershell

I have the following text that comes from powershell of a foreach line by line:

```
get-content C:\temp\data.txt | where-object {$_}

output:

usuario   nombre    dni  instalacion  sede
dni  JOSE 45 grupo: SI  MURCIA
dni  ANGEL 45 grupo: SI ALMERIA
dni MARIA 56 grupo: SI  BARCELONA
dni M. PILAR 65 grupo: SI  ALBOX
dni M. PAZ 75  grupo: SI MADRID
dni FLOREN  57 grupo: SI MADRID
```

How can I insert it in an excel so that it is inserted often with the Excel.Application object and not have to put the exact column and row of powershell so that it is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please add the powershell commands you run to get that data. If it's just text, then how are the columns separated - spaces, tabs?

Comment: More than anything, it is how I could do it by inserting it in excel because I have seen that you have to do $WorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,1) and see what column and row you have to put and I don't know how to insert it without worrying about it

Comment: You can open Excel. Start the macro recorder. Copy/paste or import your data, and clean it up as you like. Stop the macro recorder. Review the VBA code, and refactor for use via PowerShell. What does the original file look like? Why are you using Get-Content vs Import-Csv? Can the tool that was used to create the file, produce the file as a genuine CSV? A Q&D (quick and dirty) option is just use all needed '-Replace' statements on the file as you read it in. You have to first convert that file into a columnar/table format before pulling it into Excel for whatever use case you require.

Comment: can some mod move the question to stackoverflow

Comment: You can do this yourself simply by cross-posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment. This is an example of one way to approach this cleanup for use.

I am using [Powershell variable squeezing](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Powershell%20variable%20squeezing%27&t=h_&ia=web) to show what is being written to the variable and output to the screen for immediate review of success or failure for results. The inclusion of the feature use is not required.

```
Clear-Host
@'
usuario   nombre    dni  instalacion  sede
dni  JOSE 45 grupo: SI  MURCIA
dni  ANGEL 45 grupo: SI ALMERIA
dni MARIA 56 grupo: SI  BARCELONA
dni M. PILAR 65 grupo: SI  ALBOX
dni M. PAZ 75  grupo: SI MADRID
dni FLOREN  57 grupo: SI MADRID
'@ | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\UserList.txt'

# Clean-up by planned property and replace with comma
Clear-Host
(
$ExcelReport = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserList.txt') -Replace '\s\s+|[ ]+(?=\d)', ',' -Replace 'dni\s', 'dni,' -replace '\sgrupo:', ',grupo:' -replace 'SI\s', 'SI,' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
)
# Results
<#
usuario nombre   dni instalacion sede     
------- ------   --- ----------- ----     
dni     JOSE     45  grupo: SI   MURCIA   
dni     ANGEL    45  grupo: SI   ALMERIA  
dni     MARIA    56  grupo: SI   BARCELONA
dni     M. PILAR 65  grupo: SI   ALBOX    
dni     M. PAZ   75  grupo: SI   MADRID   
dni     FLOREN   57  grupo: SI   MADRID
#>

# More succinctly  - Clean-up by specific space removal and replace with a comma
Clear-Host
(
$ExcelReport = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserList.txt') -Replace '\s\s+|\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)+\s|(?<=[i])+\s|(?<=[SI])+\s', ',' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
)
# Results
<#
usuario nombre   dni instalacion sede     
------- ------   --- ----------- ----     
dni     JOSE     45  grupo: SI   MURCIA   
dni     ANGEL    45  grupo: SI   ALMERIA  
dni     MARIA    56  grupo: SI   BARCELONA
dni     M. PILAR 65  grupo: SI   ALBOX    
dni     M. PAZ   75  grupo: SI   MADRID   
dni     FLOREN   57  grupo: SI   MADRID 
#>


# Convert to true CSV
$ExcelReport = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserList.txt') -Replace '\s\s+|\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)+\s|(?<=[i])+\s|(?<=[SI])+\s', ',' | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Header usuario, nombre, dni, instalacion, sede 
# Results
<#
usuario     : dni
nombre      : JOSE
dni         : 45
instalacion : grupo: SI
sede        : MURCIA

usuario     : dni
nombre      : ANGEL
dni         : 45
instalacion : grupo: SI
sede        : ALMERIA

usuario     : dni
nombre      : MARIA
dni         : 56
instalacion : grupo: SI
sede        : BARCELONA

usuario     : dni
nombre      : M. PILAR
dni         : 65
instalacion : grupo: SI
sede        : ALBOX

usuario     : dni
nombre      : M. PAZ
dni         : 75
instalacion : grupo: SI
sede        : MADRID

usuario     : dni
nombre      : FLOREN
dni         : 57
instalacion : grupo: SI
sede        : MADRID
#>
 

<#
THus enableing member dot refreenceing of properties. for leverageing as needed
in any tool that can read/use CSV files.
#>

$ExcelReport.Count
# Results
<#
6
#>

$ExcelReport | 
Select-Object -Property usuario, nombre
# Results
<#
usuario nombre  
------- ------  
dni     JOSE    
dni     ANGEL   
dni     MARIA   
dni     M. PILAR
dni     M. PAZ  
dni     FLOREN 
#>

$ExcelReport.sede
# Results
<#
MURCIA
ALMERIA
BARCELONA
ALBOX
MADRID
MADRID
#>
```

***Update:***

*As per my comment - this is what you should be using. Again, you can use whatever filename you choose.*

```
# Make avaialbe for import into MSExcel
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserList.txt') -Replace '\s\s+|\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)+\s|(?<=[i])+\s|(?<=[SI])+\s', ',' | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\UserList.csv' -Force
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserList.csv'
# Results
<#
usuario,nombre,dni,instalacion,sede
dni,JOSE,45,grupo: SI,MURCIA
dni,ANGEL,45,grupo: SI,ALMERIA
dni,MARIA,56,grupo: SI,BARCELONA
dni,M. PILAR,65,grupo: SI,ALBOX
dni,M. PAZ,75,grupo: SI,MADRID
dni,FLOREN,57,grupo: SI,MADRID
#>

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\UserList.csv' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
usuario nombre   dni instalacion sede     
------- ------   --- ----------- ----     
dni     JOSE     45  grupo: SI   MURCIA   
dni     ANGEL    45  grupo: SI   ALMERIA  
dni     MARIA    56  grupo: SI   BARCELONA
dni     M. PILAR 65  grupo: SI   ALBOX    
dni     M. PAZ   75  grupo: SI   MADRID   
dni     FLOREN   57  grupo: SI   MADRID 
#>

Start-Process -FilePath 'Excel' -ArgumentList 'D:\Temp\UserList.csv'
```

[image]

***Update***

*Call Excel via COM without creating a separate CSV file as shown above or using variables*

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                        PresentationCore,
                        PresentationFramework,
                        System.Windows.Forms,
                        Microsoft.VisualBasic
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserList.txt') -Replace '\s\s+|\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)+\s|(?<=[i])+\s|(?<=[SI])+\s', ',' | 
Set-Clipboard

$MSExcel         = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$MSExcel.visible = $True

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate((Get-Process -Name 'Excel').MainWindowTitle)

$NewWorksheet = $MSExcel.Workbooks.Add()
$Worksheet    = $NewWorksheet.Worksheets.item(1) 
$Worksheet.activate()
$Worksheet.Paste()
```

Then use the built-in MSExcel Text to Column feature on the MSEcel Data tab on the ribbon.

[image]

You can add additional code to do that as well

***Update***

As per my last comment on knowing MSExcel COM and what to do with it. You just need these lines

```
$xlRange         = $Worksheet.usedrange
$xlColA          = $Worksheet.range("A1").EntireColumn
$xlColrange      = $Worksheet.range("A1")
$xlDelimited     = 1
$xlTextQualifier = -4142
$xlTextFormat    = 2

$xlColA.texttocolumns($xlRange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$true,$false,$true,$true,$false)

$Worksheet.columns.autofit()
```

[image]

***Always update your own question. Please do not update a provided answer with your further questions, as it does not allow for folks to properly follow it.

Updating an answer means you are trying to improve the answer.

Once you get beyond what the comment section allows, you need to update your question or move the conversation to the 'Chat section' with the person you want to continue the conversation with.***

***Update as per your list comment***

If that came from a list, then you could do this for cleanup for this dataset, the rest of the code would be the same.

```
('usuario   nombre    dni  instalacion  sede
dni  JOSE 45 grupo: SI  MURCIA
dni  ANGEL 45 grupo: SI ALMERIA
dni MARIA 56 grupo: SI  BARCELONA
dni M. PILAR 65 grupo: SI  ALBOX
dni M. PAZ 75  grupo: SI MADRID
dni FLOREN  57 grupo: SI MADRID' -replace '\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)+\s|(?<=[i])+\s|(?<=[SI])+\s', ','`
 -replace 'usuario   nombre    dni, instalacion  sede', 'usuario,nombre,dni,instalacion,sede').Trim() |
Set-Clipboard
```

Comment: these variables $ExcelReport.sede ,$ExcelReport.Count,...... there is no way to put them directly into excel? without having to create a csv

Comment: In any case, it does not work for me. It puts all the data together in a row. Look at the image above, which is the output that I have to create.

Comment: As for this: ***these variables $ExcelReport.sede ,$ExcelReport.Count,...... there is no way to put them directly into excel? without having to create a csv*** , was to show you how to fix up a file. The example I posted, specifically, the last segment does what you say you want. Screen shot added. So, I am not sure what you are trying, but if you are trying to add this data use in Excel, you must clean up the file first. You do not have to create a separate csv file, you can just overwrite the data in the .txt file, simply by using the same file name.

Comment: Or are you saying you can't or don't want to alter the file on disk? If you migrate/open the data into Excel, are you saying you have no plans on saving it, thus creating a new file *.xlsx anyway? You cannot use a single variable to migrate this data into Excel. You have to parse it by property name. That's a lot of needed work, when you can just save and open as shown.

Comment: but it is no longer automatic, excel should not be touched since it will be sent by mail to an outsider who does not understand excel

Comment: That specification is something you should have stated in the original post. Based on your post, it appears as this was just for you. Either way, what I've given you as shown works to get you there, the whole T2C code, is something you can do; or are you saying, you don't know the Excel COM well enough to do this and have not looked up how? Again, the macro recorder gives you the code,  which you can refactor.